# How to mock a JSON document for test using spring boot and mockito

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking

In spring boot test, How to test a method that consumes a JSON Document (list of json object) parses it, does a processing on the data and return a list of objects.

Comment: Write code you written so far.

Comment: Add the test contents as json file in test resources, then use it for input of your test.

Comment: The question is very ambiguous. You should try to be specific, and provide sample code or at least explain further what scenario you have and what problem you are facing achieving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the Json object in your src/test/resources directory and than you can read it inside your test case and pass it as an input to your test case